# Talking from Android Adobe AIR application to local computer through USB

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, serial-port, usb

In Flash Builder, there is USB Debugging feature for mobile applications built with Adobe AIR. It lets application installed on Android devise to transmit errors and trace statements to Flash Builder.

I need to develop the same feature for my application: Android application built with Adobe AIR talks to application on my local PC.

Does anybody know what technology it could be achieved with? Do they use serial port communication, or local server? Does anybody have a piece of code that does a similar thing?

Note: I'm not interested in network debugging, just USB Debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I just googled and found this video:

[http://www.hsharma.com/tutorials/flash-builder-4-7-usb-debugging-on-ios/][1]